# Is it possible to connect a washing machine supply to a toilet supply?

Tags: washing-machine

Could I get something to enable me to connect the washing machine to this cold water pipe by the toilet?

If we have the pan connector replaced to this one with the waste pipe connection also would it work?

[image: cold water tap]

[image: pan connector]

Comment: That depends how good are you in plumbing, it will involve cutting and glueing

Comment: Usually you just need to add a Tee fitting plus the right adapters, plus remember not to flush when using the washer.

Comment: @crip659 where would you add tee fitting without cutting

Comment: @Ruskes  That is the fun part of plumbing.  With the right adapters/parts you can add almost anything, plastic pipes can bend a bit.

Comment: @Ruskes Replace the 90 elbow that feeds vertically into the stop valve - no bending or cutting required.

Comment: @SolarMike replace with what

Comment: @Ruskes a tee as you have been told…

Comment: @SolarMike maybe you could try to answer the OP question with some details how to do it